# Expression preceding parentheses must have pointer-to- function type when using functors

Tags: c++, object, functor

So, as the title states, I'm struggling to use a functor for my game server map class. I've defined the following template class to represent the sectored 3D map:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix3d {
public:
    matrix3d(uint16_t XMin, uint16_t XMax, uint16_t YMin, uint16_t YMax, uint8_t ZMin, uint8_t ZMax);

    T* operator() (uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint8_t z);

private:
    uint16_t xmin, xmax;
    uint16_t ymin, ymax;
    uint8_t zmin, zmax;

    int16_t dx, dy;
    int8_t dz;

    T* Entry; // This is an array that I new() in the class constructor.
};
```

At the start of the server I `new` a global instance that will hold the map `matrix3d<TSector *> *g_Map`(`TSector` being a struct holding a 2-dimensional 32x32 array of tiles and its flags and stuff).

I decided to overload the `()` operator to retrieve a TSector* given the corresponding coordinates from the map files:

```
template<typename T>
T* matrix3d<T>::operator() (uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint8_t z) {
    uint16_t xx = x - xmin;
    uint16_t yy = y - ymin;
    uint8_t zz = z - zmin;

    if (xx >= 0 && xx < dx
     && yy >= 0 && yy < dy
     && zz >= 0 && zz < dz)
        return &Entry[xx + dy * dx * zz + dx * yy];

    error("matrix3d::operate: Unexpected Index %d/%d/%d.\n", x, y, z);
    return Entry;

}
```

So, my problem relies at the moment of compiling this function: `LoadSector(filename, x, y, z)`, which gets called for each sector file (I have about 10.000 of these files) and retrieves the respective sector from `g_Map` to store the parsed tile contents:

```
void LoadSector(const char* FileName, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint8_t z) {
    TSector* sector = g_Map(x, y, z); // My actual problems is here.

    // BEGIN PARSING.
}
```

VS Code says: "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type".
g++ says: g_Map cannot be used as a function.

Comment: Not related to your question but you will make life easier for yourself by using a container class for `Entry` instead of raw pointers and manual memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g_Map` is a **pointer** to a `matrix3d`. In order to invoke your `operator()` on that `matrix3d` object, you need to first dereference the pointer:

```cpp
TSector* sector = (*g_Map)(x, y, z);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```cpp
TSector* sector = (*g_Map).operator()(x, y, z);
```

Alternatively :

```cpp
TSector* sector = g_Map->operator()(x, y, z);
```

Comment: I're rewritten my functions like 3 times, and it was just this tiny mistake. Thank you, this works like a charm.